# Ender 3v2 is only recognized by Windows 10 laptop upon bootup

Tags: creality-ender-3, pronterface

This might be considered a "Windows" question, but since it only happens with the Ender, I thought I would post it here.

I have a Windows 10 laptop connected to my Ender 3 V2, and I use Pronterface to control the printer. When I boot my laptop with the Ender turned on, the device is recognized, appears as COM4 in the Device Manager, and all works fine.

If I disconnect or turn off the printer with the laptop on, then reconnect it (or turn it back on), the USB does not recognize the printer and I have to restart my laptop for it to work again. Going into the Device Manager and trying to "Find new hardware" has no effect.

Stock firmware on the Ender with the CR touch (32-bit board).

Any trick to getting the laptop to recognize the Ender once booted up?